# C - Printing only selected information from mktime?

Tags: c, mktime

I am kinda stuck here with the mktime function and I would appreciate any help I can get.

So what I am doing is, having the user input a year, month and day and then run the tm structure to calculate everything like this:

**struct** tm time;

**time_t** t;

```
time.tm_year = year - 1900;
time.tm_mon = month - 1;
time.tm_mday = day;
time.tm_hour = 0;
time.tm_min = 0;
time.tm_sec = 0;
time.tm_isdst = -1;
```

And then I run the mktime function and set it equal to t:

t = **mktime**(&time);

And then I run the print function like this:

**printf**("%s", ctime(&t));

However, what I am getting via this method is this for example:

Sat Aug 23 00:00:00 2013

But what I would like the final time format to look like is this:

Mon 2013 02 11

How would I go about doing this? I think my approach with the ctime function is not really right.

Maybe I should use the strftime function?

Note that I don't need to print the current time though.

Thanks, have a good one : )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `strftime` for this. Here is an example:

```
char str[50];
struct tm *tm_info = localtime(&t);
strftime(str, 50, "%a %G %m %d", tm_info);
```

Then you can use `printf("%s\n", str)` to output the formatted date.

Thanks to Xis88 for the format.

Comment: Hello there and thanks for your reply. I thought this would be the way to go. but how would I implement it if my struct is declared like this struct tm time; instead of struct tm *time?

Comment: Well, you can simply use the reference operator to point to the struct you have: `strftime(str, 50, "%a %G %m %d", &time);`, but I am not sure what you're trying to do. Why not simply declare it as a pointer and use localtime?

Comment: Oh I figured it out, thanks a lot : ) I used &time to point to the structure and it works now properly. : )